# Get slf4j NOP implementation to log to console

Tags: java, slf4j, no-op

I want `slf4j NOP` implementation to log to the console. Currently, it just doesnt log anything, instead is there a way to have it log to the console?

My use case is I have a library (not an app) which just depends on `slf4j-api`. But some of the classes in there have main method for testing purposes. When I run those main methods, I want all the logs to go to the console without having to depend on `slf4j-log4j` binding.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[NOP](http://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/helpers/NOPLogger.html) means "no operation". Its purpose is not to do anything and thus not log anything.

Comment: Thanks. I read something which led me to believe that probably NOP could log to console too, but I must have misunderstood.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the `slf4j-simple` implementation. It will log to the console.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I do realize that but was confused by something I read which led me to believe that probably NOP could log to console too.